# SwiftUI create View and func with button tapped. Is this possible?

Tags: swiftui

When the **"Add Circle"** button is pressed, `Circle()` will be created in `VStack`.
Clicking **"Add Function for Circle"** button will add `frame`, `trim`, `stroke` functions to `Circle()`. Do you think this is possible? Edit: I added code.

Can't add it directly like a `View` without `ForEach`? As you can see, there is no `Circle()` on my code screen, and when I press the button, I want to create a circle on the code screen (SwiftUI file) and preview screen.

[image]

Code:

```
struct SampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
      VStack(spacing: 20) {
        
        // Circle here....
        //Circle()
        
        Button(action: {
          //Add Circle
          //Circle()
        }) {
          Text("Add Circle")
        }
        
        Button(action: {
          //Add Function
          //frame, stroke, trim... etc.
        }) {
          Text("Add Function for Circle")
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: show your code as text, not a picture.

Answer (score 1):

This code does what you want. It chooses a random color. You can expand the CircleStyle struct as you need to and add border, shadow and other styles to it.

```
struct CircleStyle {
    let id: Int
    let color: Color
    let shadowColor: Color
    let shadowRadius: Double
}

struct ContentView: View {

    let colorList: [Color] = [.red, .blue, .green, .yellow]

    @State var shapeList = [CircleStyle]()

    @State var maxId = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Here the circles are stacked
            ForEach(shapeList, id: \.id) { shapeStyle in
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(shapeStyle.color)
                    .shadow(color: shapeStyle.shadowColor, radius: shapeStyle.shadowRadius)
            }
        
            Button(action: {
                // Here the circle styles are created
                // You can also edit the styles with another action
                maxId += 1
                self.shapeList.append(CircleStyle(id: maxId, color: colorList.randomElement()!, shadowColor: colorList.randomElement()!, shadowRadius: Double.random(in: 0...20)))
            }) {
                Text("Add")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can easily add buttons to the `VStack`, as for
functions as you call `modifiers`,  you can apply the same principle,
using some `@State` var and add them to the desired button. It's up to you
which button you want to add modifiers to.

Adding buttons to the `VStack`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var circles = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 20){
            ForEach(0..<circles, id: \.self) { n in
                Circle().frame(width: 44, height: 44) // <-- replace 44 with var
            }
            Button(action: { circles += 1 } ) {
                Text("Add circle")
            }
            Button(action: {
                // you can do the rest, using var for use in frame width etc...
            } ) {
                Text("Add function for circle")
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

EDIT-1: only 1 button

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showCircles = false
    @State var w: CGFloat = 66
    @State var h: CGFloat = 66

    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 20){
            if showCircles {
                Circle().frame(width: w, height: h)
            }
            Button(action: { showCircles = true } ) {
                Text("Add circle")
            }
            Button(action: {
                w = 22
                h = 22
            } ) {
                Text("Add function for circle")
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but Can't add it directly like a ```View``` without ```ForEach```? As you can see, there is no ```Circle()``` on my code screen, and when I press the button, I want to create a circle on the code screen (SwiftUI file) and preview screen.

Comment: updated my answer with just 1 button. Is this what you want?

Comment: I thought about it but this is not what I want to do.

Comment: can you explain what you want? Does a circle appear when you tap on the "Add" button?